# Display list as grid (like days in calendar)

Tags: html, css

I'm learning `css` and want to code small calendar. I tried some templates and ended up with this:

Somehow I can't **change the width of days block** to correspond with headers width and can only **regulate weeks by percent**. How can it be done properly?

```css
ul {list-style-type: none;}

.header {
  color: white;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  text-align: center;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header ul li {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

/* Month header */
.month {
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Month list */
.month ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

/* Previous button inside month header */
.month .prev {
  color: #1abc9c;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Next button */
.month .next {
  color: #1abc9c;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Days (1-31) */
.days {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.days li {
  margin: px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13.5%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Highlight the "current" day */
.days li .active {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white !important
}

.days li .left {
  padding: 5px;
  color: gray !important
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Archive<span style="font-size:18px"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="month">
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
    <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
    <li>December 2022</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="days">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li><span class="active">4</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">5</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">6</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">7</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">8</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">9</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">10</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">11</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">12</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">13</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">14</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">15</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">16</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">17</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">18</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">19</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">20</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">21</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">22</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">23</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">24</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">25</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">26</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">27</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">28</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">29</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">30</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">31</span></li>
</ul>
```

Desired template like this:
[image]

Comment: please explain properly, what you want to do. Whether you want to place dates and weekdays in a straight line vertically or something else?

Comment: @SampatAheer I want to make standard calendar days grid. To place dates by weeks horizontaly. I attached expected output image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks for more information. I have created a code-pen. please let me know if it is desired output or we can improve this. Here is the codepen link and code below:

https://codepen.io/sampat-28/pen/dyKRyrd

If you want to center the calendar then use the code below on body or wrap entire code in a div and then apply this on that.

```
body{
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: center;
  margin: 30px auto;
}
```

have a nice day.

Answer (score 1):

```css
ul {list-style-type: none;}

.header {
  color: white;
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  text-align: center;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header ul li {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;

}

/* Month header */
.month {
  width: 320px;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Month list */
.month ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.month ul li {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

/* Previous button inside month header */
.month .prev {
  color: #1abc9c;
  float: left;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Next button */
.month .next {
  color: #1abc9c;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Days (1-31) */
.days {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
  width:320px;
}

.days li {
  margin: px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 42px;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Highlight the "current" day */
.days li .active {
  padding: 6px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white !important
}

.days li .left {

  color: gray !important
}
```

```html
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="styles.css">
    <title>Sample</title>
</head>
<div class="header">
  <ul>
    <li>Archive<span style="font-size:18px"></span></li>
  </ul>
</div>

<div class="month">
  <ul>
    <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
    <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
    <li>December 2022</li>
  </ul>
</div>

<ul class="days">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
  <li><span class="active">4</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">5</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">6</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">7</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">8</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">9</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">10</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">11</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">12</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">13</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">14</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">15</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">16</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">17</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">18</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">19</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">20</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">21</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">22</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">23</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">24</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">25</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">26</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">27</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">28</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">29</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">30</span></li>
  <li><span class="left">31</span></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: eight days in a week :-)

Answer (score 0):

you can compare, I hope it helps

```css
/*add*/
.wrap {
  width: 320px;
}

/*changes */
ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(7, 1fr);
}

/*changes */

.header {
  color: white;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  text-align: center;
}

.header ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

.header ul li {
  padding-top: 7px;
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

/*changes */
/* Month header */
.month {
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
  background: black;
  text-align: center;
}

/* Month list */
/*changes */

.month ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  justify-content: space-around;
  align-items: center;
  height: 100%;
}

/*changes */
.month ul li {
  color: white;
  font-size: 20px;
  letter-spacing: 3px;
}

/* Previous button inside month header */
.month .prev {
  color: #1abc9c;
  float: left;
}

/* Next button */
.month .next {
  color: #1abc9c;
  float: right;
  padding-top: 5px;
}

/* Days (1-31) */
.days {
  padding: 10px 10px;
  background: white;
  margin: 0;
}

.days li {
  margin: px;
  list-style-type: none;
  display: inline-block;
  width: 13.5%;
  text-align: left;
  margin-bottom: 5px;
  font-size: 12px;
  color: black;
  font-weight: bold;
}

/* Highlight the "current" day */
.days li .active {
  padding: 5px;
  background: #1abc9c;
  color: white !important;
}

.days li .left {
  color: gray !important;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8" />
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0" />
    <title>Document</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css.css" />
  </head>
  <body>
  <!-- add div with wrap class -->
    <div class="wrap">
      <div class="header">
        <ul>
          <li>Archive<span style="font-size: 18px"></span></li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <div class="month">
        <ul>
          <li class="prev">&#10094;</li>
          <li>December 2022</li>
          <li class="next">&#10095;</li>
        </ul>
      </div>

      <ul class="days">
        <li>1</li>
        <li>2</li>
        <li>3</li>
        <li><span class="active">4</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">5</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">6</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">7</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">8</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">9</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">10</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">11</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">12</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">13</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">14</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">15</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">16</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">17</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">18</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">19</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">20</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">21</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">22</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">23</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">24</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">25</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">26</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">27</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">28</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">29</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">30</span></li>
        <li><span class="left">31</span></li>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).